# Converting character vector to list of data frames of same names

Tags: r

I have a set of data frames - let us say called report_001, report_002, report_003 and so on - I have the names of them in a character vector such as:

```
n <- c('report_001', 'report_002', 'report_003')
```

I need to turn this into a list of data frames as follows:

```
dfList <- list(report_001 = report_001, report_002 = report_002, report_003 = report_003)
```

So that I can index like this:

```
dfList[['report_002']]
```

However, since I have a large number of data frames, I don't want to do this manually. Trying to do something like this, has not worked:

```
dfList <- sapply(n, function(x) assign(x, as.name(x)))
```

For this question, what those data frames are is not important. To keep things simple, I can have:

```
report_001 <- mtcars
report_002 <- mtcars
report_003 <- mtcars
```

How can I achieve auto conversion of my names of data frames into a list of data frames of same name indices?

Comment: Wow...that simple and in base. Did not even know. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
report_001 <- mtcars
report_002 <- mtcars
report_003 <- mtcars
n <- c('report_001', 'report_002', 'report_003')
dfList <- mget(n)
head(dfList[['report_001']])
#                    mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am
# Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1
# Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0
# Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0
```

Comment: While this works like a champ, I am have terrible trouble invoking a shiny app after constructing this list with my data set. All looks good, but when I invoke even blank UI with blank server, I get Error : value for ‘report_001’ not found. For the life of me, I can't figure out. Strangely, when I gsub commas in a column, the same error moves to the next data frame in the list. Any thoughts?

Comment: For follow-up questions that exceed the scope of your first question it is best to create another question entirely. It is terribly difficult to help otherwise.